# Understanding もな

Tags: particles, particle-も

> 「お前それさえ言っときゃ済むと思ってんな!?　謝れっつってんじゃねえよ改善しろっつってんだよ。いつか死ぬぞあんな無茶な戦い方しやがって！　代えの部品が底ついたってのに、次の補充まで修理できねぇぞ！」
>
> 「二号機が」
>
> 「ああ有るなぁどっかの戦隊長が毎っ回毎っ回機体ぶっ壊すせいで置いてある予備が二機**もな**！　他のプロセッサーの三倍も整備の手間かけさせやがって、てめぇ何様だ王子様か!?」

From
86─エイティシックス─
安里アサト

How should I understand the もな? I know な is an end particle for seeking agreement. But what is the も? Is anything omitted after もな?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This も is for indicating the marked number is large; "no fewer than" or "as many as". Nothing is omitted in this sentence, but the verb that normally comes after the も is found at the beginning of the sentence (倒置/anastrophe). In the normal word order, the sentence in question is:

> ああ、(どっかの戦隊長が毎っ回毎っ回機体ぶっ壊すせいで置いてある→)予備が**二機も有るなぁ**！
>
> Indeed, there are (not one but) TWO spares (←I keep coz some commander I know destroys his unit every single time)!
>
> <sup>(どっかの戦隊長 is indirectly referring to "you".)</sup>